# Wordpress shortcode inside bootstrap popup

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form-7, bootstrap-popover

Can i somehow insert a CF7 form shortcode inside bootstrap popover?
This doesnt work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.toolbox_trigger a').popover({
    content: '[contact-form-7 id="1" title="Callback"]', 
    html: true, 
    placement: "bottom",
    trigger: "focus",
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but you can try with 
`content: '<?php [contact-form-7 id="1" title="Callback"] ?>' or  content: '<?php echo [contact-form-7 id="1" title="Callback"] ?>'`

Comment: if you look at this article it explains it better that we can use PHP inside of JS if there is a requirement "http://wptricks.co.uk/include-php-variables-into-jquery/#.V-PiSEYrJhE"